Not able to login using AD user with XRDP
I have installed & configured xrdp on Ubuntu 20.04 & 24.04 & tried logging with a AD user but I am unable login using xrdp. I have also tried installing xrdp on mint xfce still getting same issue.
Can someone help on how to configure XRDP to use AD user to login.

